# How to Get Group Head Result another Table MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have Two Table

**group**

```
gid| account         | head
---------------------------------
1  | first cash      | CashinHand
2  | second cash     | CashinHand
3  | third  cash     | CashinHand
4  | office expense  | Expense
```

**trans**

```
tid| particular      | amount
------------------------------
1  | first cash      | 100
2  | office expense  | 300
3  | second cash     | 130
4  | third  cash     | 50
5  | first cash      | 110
6  | office expense  | 750
```

// I want Get Report All Cash  . It depend Group table Head `CashinHand`
like this

```
tid| particular      | amount
------------------------------
1  | first cash      | 100
3  | second cash     | 130
4  | third  cash     | 50
5  | first cash      | 110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` your two tables and check that the account `head` for a given transaction is `CashInHand`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trans t
JOIN `group` g ON g.account = t.particular
WHERE g.head = 'CashInHand'
```

Output:

```
tid     particular      amount
1       first cash      100
3       second cash     130
4       third cash      50
5       first cash      110
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58450a/1)